# and error at main in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm confused I'm trying to learn more about java.lang.System and I'm facing what I think a stupid error but actually could not declare it .

my program is :

```
package TheProggrammerOfTheFuture;

import java.lang.System;

public class d {

public class Main {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Time time1=new Time();  
        System.out.println("For first         object:"+time1.getHour()+':'+time1.getMinute()+':'+time1.getSecond());  
}  

}

public class Time {  
    private int hour;  
    private int minute;  
    private int second;  
    ////////////////////  
    public Time()  
    {  
        long totalMilliSeconds=System.currentTimeMillis();  
        long totalSeconds=totalMilliSeconds/1000;  
        this.second=(int)(totalSeconds%60);  
        long totalMinutes=totalSeconds/60;  
        this.minute=(int)(totalMinutes%60);  
        long totalHours=totalMinutes/60;  
        this.hour=(int)(totalHours%24);  
    }  
    public int getHour(){  
        return hour;  
    }  
    public int getMinute(){  
        return minute;  
    }  
    public int getSecond(){  
        return second;  
    }  
    public void display()  
    {  
        System.out.println("Time:"+hour+":"+minute+":"+second);  
    }  


}  

}
```

the error is in the `main` and it says '

`The method main cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type`

I hope you could humble and look at my program I would appropriate it with all my heart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the d class. I see no need for it. It makes you `Main` class an inner class. The file should be name `Main.java`.

If you want it that way you have it, then you need the `main` method in the `d` class.

```
public class Main {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Time time1=new Time();  
        System.out.println("For first object:"+time1.getHour()+':'+time1.getMinute()+':'+time1.getSecond());  
}
```

Also if your `Time` class is in the same file as the `Main`, `Time` can't be `public`.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        ...
    }
}

class Time {
    ...
}
```

-OR-

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        ....
    }
}
```

**Time.java**

```
public class Time{
    ...
}
```

---

Answer (score 2):

You have your Main class as an inner class. Move it to a separate class/.java source file.

The error message actually tells you all you need to know. The main method needs to be in a top level type. That is, not in an inner class and not as a second class within the same source file.

It is possible with Java to enter lots of separate classes in the same source file, however, only one can be public and that one needs to share the same name as the file itself. The main method has to go in this "top level" type.

Comment: Glad it helped and thanks for taking time to vote for the answers that helped.

Answer (score 2):

You could just remove the `public class d` and then rename your file to Main.java. You would also need to declare `Time` as just `class Time`.

EDIT:
Java by default tries to run the `public static void main(String[])` method in the class named the same as the filename. Therefore, by removing class d (Why is it even there?), and renaming to Main.java, it will run your main method successfully. You need to change `Time` because an outer public class must be in a file designated by its own name, so you can't make it public.

Answer (score 2):

write this instead: Compiles on my computer

```
import java.lang.System;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Time time1 = new Time();
    System.out.println("For first object:" + time1.getHour() + ':'
            + time1.getMinute() + ':' + time1.getSecond());
    }
}

class Time {
    private int hour; 
    private int minute;
    private int second;

    // //////////////////
    public Time() {
        long totalMilliSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalSeconds = totalMilliSeconds / 1000;
        this.second = (int) (totalSeconds % 60);
        long totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60;
        this.minute = (int) (totalMinutes % 60);
        long totalHours = totalMinutes / 60;
        this.hour = (int) (totalHours % 24);
    }

    public int getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    public int getMinute() {
        return minute;
    }

    public int getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Time:" + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
    }

}
```